# Strange steam updater behaivour with pipes

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, steam

There is a strange behaivour in the STDOUT of this program.

If I execute the program:
`./steam -command update -game "Counter-Strike Source" -dir .`
Outputs the next:

```
Checking bootstrapper version ...
Updating Installation
Determining which depot(s) to install/update...
5 depot(s) will be installed/updated
  0:02 Checking local files and building download list for depot 242 'Counter-Strike Source Shared' version 129
  0:02     Connecting content server session for version 129
  0:03     [80.239.194.162:27030] Connecting...
  0:06     [80.239.194.162:27030] Failed.  Failed to connect to 80.239.194.162:27030, errno 115 "Operation now in progress"
  0:06     [81.171.68.195:27030] Connecting...
  0:07     [81.171.68.195:27030] Connection established; handshaking...
  0:08     [81.171.68.195:27030] Sending login message...
  0:08     Fetching version 129 manifest
  ...
```

For any strange reason if I use a pipe and tee to log it into a file this way: `./steam -command update -game "Counter-Strike Source" -dir . | tee log`
The only thing that outputs the program is:

```
Checking bootstrapper version ...
Updating Installation
Determining which depot(s) to install/update...
5 depot(s) will be installed/updated
```

And nothing more. The same text is in the log file and on the screen. Still the program starts updating the files.  Any idea why is this happening?

Note: The lines that are missing are not from STDERR

Note2: ./steam doesnt create any children or extra processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess the program is checking `isatty(3)` to decide whether to display progress output. If that's the case, then you probably wouldn't get very sensible output if you did capture it to a file, because it's probably using various control characters to make the output more human-friendly.

You can try capturing the program's output when it's connected to a TTY by running:

```
script -c "./steam -command update ..." logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

`tee` has a dual purpose -- it reads from standard input and writes the output to the specified file *and to its standard output*. As a result, you'll end up seeing everything that's being written to the log file on your terminal, since there's nothing to "soak up" the output from `tee`.

If you just want to write all output to a file, use output redirection instead:

```
./steam [args...] >> log
```

To include standard error:

```
./steam [args...] 2>&1 >> log
```

Comment: I thought of that, but doesnt work either. To know if these lines are from STDERR, I used `steam [options] 2>/dev/null` to take out the STDERR. But "Checking local files" and so on still where outputed

Comment: please learn to include valuable debugging information like this in your main question. Once you get more than 2 answers with 4 comments each, anyone that is trying to help you will have to read a lot just to find this important piece of information. To help with your question, my guess is that some child or remote process of `./stream` is generating that output. As I don't have CounterStrike, I don't have a way to test this theory. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks, but sadly there arent any extra processes of ./steam. I have updated the question with this details

Comment: sounds crazy (and maybe shell heads will correct me that such a thing just isn't possible), but an easy thing to try is `3>&1`, then `4>&1`, .... etc to see if somehow `./stream` is writing to an extra file handle. (And then of course, per my previous comment, include this information in you original question ;-) ). Good luck.